# VPN over Tor Firewall Config

Tags: configuration, vpn, openvpn

I'm looking for some help with accessing my VPN over tor.  A little background..

I have a router at home that I can connect to which routes all of my traffic over tor.  The router uses port 9030.  My VPN is hosted on DigitalOcean.  Using OpenVPN on an Ubuntu 14.04 droplet.  I'm using tunnelblick to access my VPN. I'm also using uncomplicated firewall (ufw) on my VPN on DigitalOcean.

Here's the issue; I've tried opening port 9030, 9040, 9001 etc. on my firewall for my VPN but tunnelblick's status just says "Waiting for authorization from server" and never gets any response back.  I think it's my firewall but when I checked the firewall logs I can never find the exit node IP that connects to the VPN.

Any ideas on what to check for in configuration files (in OpenVPN config, tunnelblick config etc.) would be very helpful.

Thanks

EDIT:  Following are my config files and torrc

torrc for Onion Pi
https://gist.github.com/dhurley14/8d4b8d8ac98d74b1e665

torrc for DigitalOcean VPN
https://gist.github.com/dhurley14/264754ff2eafb844ad9b

UPDATE 2:
This is what tunnelblick tells me when I try to connect to the VPN from my Onion Pi Access Point.  I changed the client and server config to allow for TCP connections and updated the firewall to allow tcp connections on port 9001.  I also ran the three commands in the terminal.  Getting closer I think.
[image: authorizing image]
[image: tunnelblick error]

Comment: Post your torrc, openvpn client and server config and am I getting you right that you want to access your VPN from your VPN router?

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin Hi So basically I've built an [Onion Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview) and would like to access my VPN on DigitalOcean while connected to the Onion Pi access point.  I'm at work so I don't have access to my VPN configs but I can update the post later tonight.  Thanks for your interest.

Comment: OK! and by the way - you're not the first one to have troubles with OnionPi. I'm building an alternative solution for full-tor router, so I'll be able to help you for sure. Update your post with configs and let's solve this!

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin so I couldn't add the other two links as I don't have enough karma to post more than two links but here are the others 

client OpenVPN config file
https://gist.github.com/dhurley14/a0e24e092cbc5c25dfaa

DigitalOcean OpenVPN server.conf file
https://gist.github.com/dhurley14/1ba7653f943998052e25

Comment: OK, transmission received, in progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems to be an answer breaking through. First - **never** use a UDP for VPN, especially when you'll be SCPing large files you will see the problems. TCP and it will be just fine. Second - on your firewall it must depend on ;)  - post your firewall rules, please. You need to make an exception for tunnel packets. Use/make a separate user for it - like `openvpn` - it will be much easier to help your packets to pass through

UPDATE:

try to replace XXX by your DO vpn

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -j RETURN
```

let's see what will happen

Comment: Okay that is what I thought the firewall would be.  Thank you for your help so far.  Here is a link to the firewall rules  https://gist.github.com/dhurley14/06868416850c6fc77cf9

Comment: OK let's try some - see my edit

Comment: I'm assuming those lines go in my firewall rules file right?

Comment: Try them from a root command prompt for a start, give it a try

Comment: The tunnel is working? A message you have screenshoted seems to be just a warning. Check your tunnel and tor working properly together

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37396/discussion-between-devin-hurley-and-alexey-vesnin).